# Get json data on go websocket server

Tags: json, go, websocket

When I send from js client `socket.send('{"text":"111"}')` and get this on server, by `websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &data)`, data remain empty. I use "golang.org/x/net/websocket"

```
type (
    Msg struct {
        clientKey string
        text string
    }

    NewClientEvent struct {
        clientKey string
        msgChan chan *Msg
    }

    Item struct {
        text string
    }
)

var (
    clientRequests = make(chan *NewClientEvent, 100)
    clientDisconnects = make(chan string, 100)
    messages = make(chan *Msg, 100)
)

func ChatServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    msgChan := make(chan *Msg, 100)
    clientKey := time.Now().String()

    clientRequests <- &NewClientEvent{clientKey, msgChan}
    defer func(){ clientDisconnects <- clientKey}()

    go func(){
        for msg := range msgChan{
            ws.Write([]byte(msg.text))
        }
    }()
    for {
        var data Item
        err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error: ", err.Error())
            return
        }
        messages <- &Msg{clientKey, data.text}
    }
}
```

But if I try send `socket.send('"text"')` and get it by this:

```
var data string
err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error: ", err.Error())
                return
            }
            messages <- &Msg{clientKey, data}
```

everything is working.

Comment: Which websocket package are you using, gorillas or just default

Comment: golang.org/x/net/websocket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are you'll need to define your struct before you can use `JSON.receive` on an object like

`{ "text": "Hi" }`

```
type socketData struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}
```

Then

```
data := &socketData{}

websocket.JSON.receive(ws, &data)

log.Println(data.Text) // Hi
```

If you're going to be sending random data that you can't really define a struct for (though this is the preferred way of doing it) you can just declare an `interface{}`

```
var data map[string]interface{}

log.Println(data["text"].(string)) // Hi
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Jp5qKtiUGw

Comment: Thanks, it's working. The problem was in `struct { text string }`. I replaced `text string` to `Text string` and it's really helped. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @SamuelLoog I haven't looked at the source but I'm sure `JSON.receive` calls `json.Unmarshal` in its source, which `json.Unmarshal` requires the struct fields to be exported, by using a capital letter on their properties, so if you use `text string` it won't work but `Text string` is exported so it works

Comment: As a go newbie this is the thing that tripped me up the most about a simple websocket server. It makes sense - but I think I would have thrown in the towel before figuring it out on my own. Thank you, thank you, thank you!